# How to store apache logs into mongodb using fluentd?

Tags: json, mongodb, fluent

I am using "FLUENTD" data collector for storing apache logs into MongoDB.I did necessary changes in td-agent configuration files like

```
<source>
  @type tail

  format apache2

  path C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\access.log

  tag mongo.apache
</source>
```

and

```
<match mongo.**>
  # plugin type

  @type mongo

  # mongodb db + collection

  database apache

  collection access


  # mongodb host + port

  host localhost

  port 27017


  # interval

  flush_interval 10s

  # make sure to include the time key

  include_time_key true

</match>
```

Did all changes in td-agent.conf file;

Path of log file is C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\access

path of position file is C:\var\log\td-agent\apache2.access_log.pos

To test the configuration, pinged the apache server using command;
    ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost/
This command is provided by http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/apache-to-mongodb    inorder to send logs to mongodb and I followed that tutorial to send logs to mongodb
Everything works good. Database and collection were also created,
but the logs files were not stored in MongoDB.
And also installed "Apache Group" to work with apache bench.